# How can I return large strings from a Service via AIDL?

Tags: android, aidl

I want to get xml in a service and return that xml-string via AIDL. Today, I realized that the calling app receives only a null-value when this string is very long. I tested a bit and found, that the limit for the string-length seems to be about 520000 characters, which is near 512*1024=524288. Java stores strings internally as UTF-16 and I think, but I'm not sure, that each character is internally (at least) two bytes big, so this limit would be at 1MB.

Now, I want to know if this limit is documented anywhere or if anyone had problems with it before. Does anyone know how I can easily return such big strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I want to know if this limit is documented anywhere or if anyone had problems with it before.

AFAIK, it is not formally documented, but there is a ~1MB limit on the contents of an IPC call, no matter how that is accomplished (AIDL, broadcast `Intent`, etc.) or what the data is (string, bitmap, other form of byte array, etc.).

> Does anyone know how I can easily return such big strings?

Use a file. If you wish, serve the file via a `ContentProvider` and `openFile()`, supplying the `Uri` to the content in the AIDL response.

Comment: There is a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor you can use as in/out parameter of your method defined in AIDL. Then you can use this file descriptor to read the String content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is limited.

Do not send the String directly, the best thing to do is store it in `SQLite` then call it back anywhere you need the String.